# Value does not apply to variable in SQL Anywhere

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

when I try to execute this function I get a error. When I execute the command without a function and without using variables it works, therefore I think the value does not apply to my variable, the declaration or the setting of variable does not work. It doesn't matter if I use SELECT or SET to set the variable, I get the same error which literally just says: The command could not be executed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ueberpruefe_kfz_status (@kennzeichen CHAR(15))
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ergebnis VARCHAR

    SELECT STATUS
    INTO @ergebnis
    FROM KFZ
    WHERE KENNZEICHEN = @kennzeichen

    RETURN @ergebnis
END
```

Here are some screenshots of the structure, sample data and the error:
https://picload.org/folder/ldpwa.html

Comment: Can you share your KFZ table structure and exact error message that you are getting ?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and results of the `Select` statement?

Comment: I added some screenshots.

Comment: For those curious, the rough translation of the error message in the screen shots is "An error occurred while reading the results of the SQL statement. The results are incorrect or incomplete."

Comment: What data type is kennzeichen in kfz?   Are you compairing a varchar datatype to a char data type and the padded spaces pf char causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your table structure seen in the image, it seems like your column `STATUS` is of type `CHAR`.
Try to Change your function return type from VARCHAR to CHAR like-

```
RETURNS CHAR
```

And type of variable @ergebnis to CHAR like-

```
DECLARE @ergebnis CHAR
```

You may specify `length` along with CHAR, like CHAR(15), which should be `greater than or equal to the length of your STATUS column`.